# How to visualize a category (of "combinatorial" maps)

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory, soft-question, visualization

This is a practical and very soft question, with the combinatorial database http://www.findstat.org in mind.

I have a few, around 20, families of combinatorial objects, for example Dyck paths, permutations, perfect matchings, graphs, etc., together with a few, around 200, maps between them.  The maps need not be injective or surjective or have any special properties.  (Except perhaps that they appear in the literature and are therefore "interesting".)

Some examples of such maps might be the reversal of a Dyck path, various classical maps that send a Dyck path to a 321-avoiding permutation, the map that sends a permutation to its shape under the Robinson-Schensted correspondence, etc.

Thus, we have (a very small) category, which I'd like to visualize.

The aspect that makes this interesting and non-trivial is, that these maps satisfies numerous identities: many maps are involutions, some are idempotent, many maps commute with other maps or are conjugate to other maps, etc.  I have all these data.

So, more precisely: I'm looking for a way to visualize (graphically!) these identities.

Comment: Silly remark: All relations between these maps can be drawn as commutative diagrams. For commutativity relations this makes sense somehow, but for idempotent maps it is kind of "over the top".

Comment: Yes.  The problem is the amount of the data.  So, to clarify: the question is about an economic visual representation.

Comment: It might be overkill, but you could put all the generating morphisms and relations into [Globular](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Globular) and then play around with it. Globular is designed to manipulate higher categories, but it should work just fine for 1-categorical data. Incidentally, do you have any map which takes as input a pair of objects, like, say, a Dyck path and a permutation? This would start using some kind of monoidal structure, which is a sort of higher categorical structure.

Comment: @TimCampion: Except that I have no idea how to use it, sounds interesting!

Comment: @TimCampion: Could you show how to visualize the identities "reverse o inverse = inverse o complement", "reverse o complement = complement o inverse", etc.?  (keeping in mind that I have a list of a few thousand such identities...)

Comment: To input the data, first create the 0-cells you need. Then create all the generating 1-cells between them (click on the source 0-cell, click "source" or press "s", click on the target 0-cell, click "target" or press "t", and a 1-cell between them is created). You can name these whatever you want. To create the identities, first construct one of the maps being identified (This may be the composite of two generating maps; in this case click on, say, the first map being composed, then the second. If there are multiple possible ways to compose these 1-cells you'll be asked which one you want).

Comment: Click "source" / press "s". Then do the same for the target, and click "target" / press "t". This builds a 2-cell from one to the other, and I suppose you want to check the option "invertible" on this 2-cell. To visualize 1-categorical diagrams, I'd think you want to project one level, but I'm a little confused by the functionality.

Comment: For some inarticulable (at present) reason, this thread suggests relation algebras and cylindrical algebras to me.  I would be only very slightly surprised if work like this were already done by someone working in algebraic logic.  Gerhard "Like A Hunch, You Know?" Paseman, 2016.12.28.

Comment: The 0-cell approach seems promising to me -- depending on what, in the end, you are after. In addition, just as a practical approach, you might consider constructing your diagrams and templates in colour-coded layers that correspond to atomic combinations of the families, then superimpose and compose the layers as on one hand you dive deeper into the complexity and on the other assemble the whole.

Answer (score 3):

Despite some interesting proposals given in the comments of the question, I finally ended up with a rather straightforward listing, mainly because the amount of data is quite large.  An example can be studied at http://findstat.org/Mp00023.